# The question given to me was to create a new dictionary with inverted key value pairs from the original dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

create a new dictionary(`new_dict`) with inverted key-value pairs from the original dictionary (`my_dict`)

```
def invert(dic_t):
new_dict={}
for key,value in dic_t.items():
   new_dict[key]=value
   new_dict[value]=key

return new_dict

my_dict = {
   "A": "B", 
   "C": "D",
   "E": "F"
 }
print(invert(my_dict))
```

**Output:**

```
{'A': 'B', 'B': 'A', 'C': 'D', 'D': 'C', 'E': 'F', 'F': 'E'}
```

I am new to python so any help would be useful

Comment: `new_dict[key]=value` is just the same as what is in the original dictionary. Remove that line and your code will work.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is correct, you just have to remove the line `new_dict[key]=value` as this represents the same old dictionary

```
def invert(dic_t):
    new_dict={}
    for key,value in dic_t.items():
        # new_dict[key]=value
        new_dict[value]=key

   return new_dict
```

Also, you can use dictionary comprehension if you are looking for an one-line answer!

```
def invert(dict_t):
    return {v:k for k, v in dict_t.items()}
```